# firestore query issues with 500 concurrent clients

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

I am doing some stress testing on my project and need your help in understanding the behavior. I have a web server which accepts json data from users and stores it in a firestore collection. Users can query this data. Document json only has two fields id1 and id2 and both are strings. Now as part of my stress test I start 500 threads to mimic 500 clients which query the collection to give each thread the documents where id1 == thread_id like this:

```
query := client.Collection("mycollection").Where("id1", ==, my_id)    
iter := query.Documents(ctx)                          
snapList, err = iter.GetAll()
```

I see two issues:

1. some of these queries are taking so long upto 20 seconds to return.
2. Some of the queries fail with connection error/io time out. I am using go sdk.

> "message":"error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp x.x.x.x:443: i/o timeout""}

as per firestore documentation uptop 1 million concurrent clients are allowed. Then why am I getting issues on just 500? Even running this test on an empty collection I observe the same behavior. Is there any other rate limit that I am missing?
New

Answer (score 1):

When adding load to Firestore it is recommended to follow the 500/50/5 rule, as explained in the documentation on [ramping up traffic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#ramping_up_traffic):

> You should gradually ramp up traffic to new collections or lexicographically close documents to give Cloud Firestore sufficient time to prepare documents for increased traffic. We recommend starting with a maximum of 500 operations per second to a new collection and then increasing traffic by 50% every 5 minutes. You can similarly ramp up your write traffic, but keep in mind the [Cloud Firestore Standard Limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions). Be sure that operations are distributed relatively evenly throughout the key range. This is called the "500/50/5" rule.

So you might want to start with a lower number of threads, and then increase 50% every 5 minutes until you reach the desired load. Some of the SDKs even have support classes for this, such as the [BulkWriter in Node.js](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#bulkWriter).

Comment: This is query load not write load. I did read about the 500/50/5 rule but that seems to be for a new collection. I see same behavior on existing collection too. Also the same behavior if I reduce threads to 300 and include a random sleep of 1-10 seconds  in each thread before making API call.

Comment: "This is query load not write load" Write loads can't be ramped up. The 500/50/5 rule is for read loads on any data, not just new collections.  Sorry to hear applying the strategy outlined isn't working for you.

 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying. So how long a collection is considered “new”? Is it based on when the collection was created or how much load has been run on it? Also while deploying on production where we don’t have any control on concurrent clients accessing the data on a new deployment how as a developer I ensure the 500/50/5 rule. For example once I deploy on production, many clients will start doing query to fetch data.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "new" here. The 500/50/5 rule for ramping up read load is not dependent on the age of a collection.

Comment: “You should gradually ramp up traffic to “new” collections or lexicographically close documents to give Cloud Firestore sufficient time to prepare documents for increased traffic.” This is from the “ramping up traffic” documentation of Firestore. So what is it referring to as “new” collection here? What is the definition of new?